# In MYSQL, querying names of products stored in 5 warehouses that has SUM quantity > 100 for each product

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me to make a query using mysql to show the products(product.name) that have total quantity SUM(goods.quantity) > 100 in all 5 warehouses, specifying the warehouse(warehouse.name) with the greatest quantity of each product. Here is the scheme of all tables for better understanding:

[image of warehouses database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKvMS.png)

I am trying this query:

```
SELECT product.name AS product, warehouse.name AS warehouse 
FROM product, warehouse, goods 
WHERE goods.productId = product.id AND goods.warehouseId = warehouse.id 
GROUP BY product.name, warehouse.name 
HAVING SUM(goods.quantity)>100;
```

it gives me the following:

| product | warehouse |
| --- | --- |
| engine | New York |
| right back door | New York |
| main frame | London |
| left back door | London |
| back lights | London |
| steering wheel | Sydney |
| wheel | Toronto |
| car cleaner | Toronto |

But it only shows products that have `goods.quantity > 100`, not the `SUM(goods.quantity) > 100` in all warehouses.

Besides, it doesn't show warehouse with the greatest quantity of each product, but any warehouse that has this product.

Comment: Provide sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) and desired output for this data.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Unrelated, but: Don't use comma-separated joins. Use `INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc. instead. These explicit joins were introduced in standard SQL in 1992. That was before MySQL even existed. My advice: Dismiss the teacher, book or tutorial that teaches you this ancient syntax.

Comment: The main problem with your query is that you group by product and warehouse. That means you are one the level of a goods row and `SUM(quantity)` is the same as `quantity`. You want to look at one product instead, i.e. group by product.

Comment: right, but when I group by just product.name it gives me an error ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY, so it requires grouping by warehouse.name as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `SUM(goods.quantity)` in the selected fields to show that number
also you could  `ORDER BY SUM(goods.quantity) DESC` so the highest quantity is at the top.

```sql
SELECT product.name AS product, warehouse.name AS warehouse, SUM(goods.quantity) FROM product, warehouse, goods WHERE goods.productId = product.id AND goods.warehouseId = warehouse.id GROUP BY product.name, warehouse.name HAVING SUM(goods.quantity)>100;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives the same outcome, just adding one more column SUM(goods quantity) - that column should not be in the selected fields. It's still not showing the warehouse that has the greatest quantity and not showing products that have goods.quantity<100 in each warehouse but have SUM(goods.quantity) > 100 totally in all warehouses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using you query as subquery result for count the numer of warehouse

```
    select products 
    from  (
        SELECT product.name AS product, warehouse.name AS warehouse 
        FROM product
        INNER JOIN warehouse  goods.warehouseId = warehouse.id 
        INNER JOIN  goods goods.productId = product.id AND
        WHERE goods.productId = product.id AND goods.warehouseId = warehouse.id 
        GROUP BY product.name, warehouse.name 
        HAVING SUM(goods.quantity)>100;

    ) t 
    group by products
    having count(distinct warehouse) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this step by step. First you need the total quantity and the maximum quantity per product. Thus you can decide whether to show this product and what warehouse to display then. This means an aggregation first, then some joins.

At last you must be prepared that there are ties (two warehouses with the same maximum quantity per product). You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a list of the top warehouses.

```
select 
  p.id,
  p.name as product_name,
  group_concat(w.name) as warehouse_names
from
(
  select 
    productid, 
    max(quantity) as max_qantity
  from goods
  group by productid
  having sum(quantity) > 100
) base
join product p on p.id = base.productid
join goods g on g.productid = base.productid and p.quantity = base.max_qantity
join warehouse w on w.id = g.warehouseid
group by p.id
order by product_name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This one works perfectly, I just tried it. Though, It is far beyond my understanding of SQL, I can't fully comprehend what you've written :(

Comment: Look at the base subquery first. Per product I take the maximum quantity. But I only take products with a total of > 100. You can run this stand-alone to see its result. Now, to this result I join the product table to get the product name. Then I join goods again, because thus I find the warehouse(s) with this quantity for the product. I join the warehouse table then to get the warehouse name. At last I aggregate again, because I may have two rows for a product when two warehouses have the same top quantity. So, group by product again to get one result row per product.